# google developers console log with unexplained errors

Tags: google-app-engine, logging

Quite suddenly, after years of running and developing this application, the log-file shown at Google developers console is filling up with entries marked with the double exclamation mark error, but with no error description when expanded. It has been going on for days now, and is making the logging absolutely useless. Everything else is drowning in these seemingly false error messages.

What can I do, except pay $150 for the right to send them an email?

Comment: we would need a bit more info here. Right now, it's impossible to say. Include screenshots maybe?

Comment: Here's a screenshot: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/184825/gnyscc/dev_console_err.png

Comment: Reported here though: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11597

Should I delete my questions?

Comment: Can you expand the "index.html" line inside the error further?

Comment: No. It's fully expanded as you see it.

Comment: @NilsR, please leave the Q here, too -- we monitor many channels, but this tag on stack overflow is one of them, and the monitoring is done by different teams so this one may be noticed before the other (or viceversa).  Plus, posting the future resolution here may help other future users with similar problems.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok. There's one more detail I can mention. Many (but not all) times the expanded error shows the page name twice. Not sure it helps, but should be mentioned. Illustration of this in screen shots of old style log: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/184825/gnyscc/old_dev_console_err.png and new style log: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/184825/gnyscc/new_dev_console_err.png

Answer (score 0):

tl:dr Don't have print statements in your request handler!

With the help of a friendly google person looking at my issue report, I found the trigger for the empty errors in the log file:

Print statements in the request handler was the cause. I had forgotten to remove them after a quick local test. Updating a version with those removed stopped the errors immediately, so it seems pretty clear.